# Ways to show protected image on UI

Tags: java, image, security, amazon-s3, microservices

I am curious to know, how to show any image or document which is stored on a private S3 bucket and I need to show it on UI to some authorized users. Just like facebook and instagram do it, to secure their images. I can not put images on a public bucket otherwise anyone can view and download it and it won't be secure. I was thinking about some solutions but every solution has it's own pros and cons. I think about below solutions:

**Solution 1:**
I can put all the images in a private S3 bucket and an auth token can be associated with image url as a query param. This image url would be passed to image server and image server will validate the auth token. If it is a valid one then, image would be fetched from private S3 bucket to image server and downloaded to client in byte array.

This approach has multiple disadvantages like:

1. Image has to travel from S3 bucket to image server and again image server to client device. It will add more latency and this would be increased with size of image.
2. This approach is not scalable. If I think that 100 image read requests are coming  in a second and every image has a size of 5MB, then approx 500MB content would present in the memory every time. And with the time when traffic would be on it's peak, server goes down.
3. I can think to cache images for faster response but image caching will take a lot of space and for the request of every server above problems would occur.

**Solution 2**
We can think to bypass image server and try to download image from the S3 bucket directly to the client device. If user is logged in, then client can download images using secret key of private bucket. Again this approach has some advantages:

1. we have to configure secret key of private bucket in client devices like Android, IOS, web, etc. There are high chances to leak secret key from the frontend resources.
2. In future if I think to replicate image content for faster service in different geographical locations, then it is hard to maintain different secret key for each bucket.

Apart from that other solution which can serve our purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 is good, but you don't need a server... Amazon S3 can do it for you.

When your application wants to provide a link to a private object, it can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides access to a private object. It can be included in your HTML page (eg `<img src="...">`) or even as a direct URL.

The beauty of this approach is that your app can generate a pre-signed URL in a few lines of code (no call to AWS required) and then Amazon S3 will do all the serving for you. This means there is less load on your application server and it is highly scalable.

Comment: But in that case we have to create new pre-signed url for every user. Suppose we have 500M active users at a time. Then, is it a good thing to create that much pre-signed urls?

Comment: Pre-signed URLs don't 'exist' anywhere. They are just a calculated checksum that says "Allow access to this object before this time". Amazon S3 will verify the pre-signed URL when it is received. You can create as many as you want. You do not "create a pre-signed url for every user". Rather, when you want to serve a page that references a private object, your app will verify that the user is entitled to access the content and, if so, will create the pre-signed URL at that time, valid for the next 5 minutes (for example).